# Department wise highest salary +2000

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables Employees and department

Table `employee` columns
`empid`
`name`
`salary`
`location`

Table `department` columns
`deptno`
`deptname`
`empid`
`mangerid`

Now I want to find department-wise the highest salary and then increment them by 2000

Answer (score 1):

ed: Hah It didn't occur to me that you actually meant update the rows, I was thinking you just wanted to retrieve the values. @Ajith Sasidharan's answer is the fuller one.

It seems odd that your department table references the employee table instead of the other way around, however this should do what you want:

```
SELECT
  d.deptno, 
  d.deptname, 
  max(e.salary+2000)
FROM
  department d
INNER JOIN
  employee e
ON 
  e.empid = d.empid
GROUP BY 
  d.deptno, d.deptname;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update emp
set sal = sal + 2000
where empid in (
select empid from dept where (deptno,sal) in (
select d.deptno,max(e.sal)
    from emp e,
    dept d
    where e.empid = d.empid
    group by deptno));
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
    select e.name,e.salary,d.name as Department 
    from employee e join dept d on e.dept = d.id 
    where (e.salary, e.dept) IN (
      select max(salary), dept 
      from employee join dept on (employee.dept = dept.id)
      group by employee.dept
    );
```

Comment: Answers including code should have at least a minumum description explaining how the code works and why it answers to the question.